# duplicated column in jpa mapping when using @AttributeOverride for embeddedClasses

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've these classes :

```
public class InventoryItemTbEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "UUID")
    private UUID uuid;
    ....
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "userId", column = @Column(name = "LOCATION_CHANGE_USERID")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "date", column = @Column(name = "LOCATION_CHANGE_DATE")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "program", column = @Column(name = "LOCATION_CHANGE_PROGRAM")),
    })
    private RowAuditEntity locationChangeAudit;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "userId", column = @Column(name = "DISPOSITION_CHANGE_USERID")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "date", column = @Column(name = "DISPOSITION_CHANGE_DATE")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "program", column = @Column(name = "DISPOSITION_CHANGE_PROGRAM")),
    })
    private RowAuditEntity dispositionChangeAudit;

    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "userId", column = @Column(name = "ROW_CHANGE_USERID")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "date", column = @Column(name = "ROW_CHANGE_DATE")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "program", column = @Column(name = "ROW_CHANGE_PROGRAM"))
    })    @Embedded
    private RowAuditEntity changeAudit;
```

and

```
@Embeddable
public class RowAuditEntity {

    @Nonnull
    protected String program;

    @Nonnull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    protected OffsetDateTime date;

    @Nonnull
    protected String userid;
```

But I get an issue when the EntityManagerFactory is initialized.
Issue is `Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Column 'userid' is duplicated in mapping for entity 'xxx.jpa.inventory.item.InventoryItemTbEntity' (use '@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)' when mapping multiple properties to the same column)`

I'm using Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.6.Final.
It seems Hibernate don't recognise @AttributeOverrides/@AttributeOverride annotation.

I already browsed a lot of forums, sites, ... for a solution or to found the reason, but unfortunately I found nothing.

Can someone help me with ?

@AttributeOverrides/@AttributeOverride should be interpreted by hibernate